# How to sync local Database to server database in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sync my database from local server to web server when some changes happen in the my local database it should get updated on the web server each time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you clarify the question, it will be very difficult to answer.

For example you could mention OS, language, preferred method.

Maybe you can just use some db tool like heidisql to download and upload the database.

You could probably automate the task with a shell script on the local machine. Ie mysqldump the database into a file, and then upload it / post it to an import script on the remote server.